# add command INSIDE batch file to generate text log (launched by double click)

Tags: logging, batch-file, cmd

Advanced thanks to anyone who is stopping by to read this. Here's my scenario:

**SCENARIO**

1. OS is w7px64. I have not worked with .bat files before, but have some familiarity with cmd.
2. I've created a successful .bat file with several dozen commands, modifying processes, services, scheduled tasks, and power schemes (using commands such as SC, net stop, schtasks, powercfg, etc.).
3. I will always launch the .bat by double-clicking in Windows Explorer (will never initiate launch from within CMD itself).
4. The file ends with a pause command, to keep cmd window open after completion of all tasks, enabling me to scroll through results.
5. The file contains only the commands mentioned above: no use of echo or anything else. I like seeing the full results (it helps in my troubleshooting).

**ISSUES**

Although the file and commands work perfectly for my needs, the results are too long for cmd (even after maximizing buffers in cmd settings); by the time the last command is executed, I can no longer scroll back up to the first commands -- cmd has purged them due to a space limitation.

**GOAL**

I would like a way for all of the above to continue as-is (even if I can't read all the way up in CMD) but also to add a command INSIDE the .bat file to SIMULTANEOUSLY output all results to a text file (exactly what appears onscreen: successes, failures, errors -- EVERYTHING)

Does such a command exist?

Also, if anyone knows a workaround to running out of space in cmd, I would love that too. Thanks again!

<

Comment: Such a command does not exist. You have to use tee, GNUWin or batch version.

Comment: Or switch to PowerShell, which has a `Tee` cmdlet.

Comment: Using some version of tee (not native to Windows CMD prompt, but available for Windows) is a good option. But if all you need to do is see the content that scrolled off the top of the window, simply edit the window properties. Right click on the window title bar and select Properties, then Layout tab. Set your Buffer Width and Height to larger values (significantly larger than Window Size). I routinely set my Width to 1000 and Height to 3000, and then I am able to scroll to see nearly everything I ever need. Obviously the change must be made before executing your command.

Comment: @dbenham: Good advice Dave, but the OP execute the Batch file via a double-click from the explorer! I used to create a shortcut to MS-DOS icon and modify its properties, but I don't know how to modify the properties of the cmd.exe session the system uses when it execute a Batch file via a double-click...

Comment: @Aacini - There is an option to save the settings automagically for the double click short cut. I don't remember what I did, but it was simple. But upon re-reading the OP's question, I see that the buffers are already maxed out, so my advice doesn't help in this case.

Comment: @user2454094: Excuse me, did you tested my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your batch files are not interactive and you do not need to see them as they run, then this will give you a log:

```
@echo off
call "d:\path here\to folder\mybatch" >"z:\logs\mybatch.log" 2>&1
start "" notepad "z:\logs\mybatch.log"
```

Comment: stderr needs to be redirected to stdout (`2>&1`), and the OP might prefer to simply TYPE the resultant log.

Comment: Good point Dave. I've added the STDERR redirection.  The OP mentioned that the CMD buffer is not large enough for his scripts output, so typing the file will lead to the same issue. :)

Comment: They could also use `more` instead of `type`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


if defined Restart goto Begin

rem TeeMyself.bat: Send output of this Batch file into screenOut.txt file
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

set Restart=True
call "%~F0" 2>&1 | Cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" 2>screenOut.txt
set Restart=
goto :EOF

:Begin

rem Place your Batch code here; for example:

rem The date: %date%, the time: %time%
dir TeeMyself.*
rem An error message sent to STDERR
verify bad

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

while ( ! WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   // Read the next line from Stdin
   var line = WScript.Stdin.ReadLine();
   // Duplicate the line to Stdout and Stderr
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line);
   WScript.Stderr.WriteLine(line);
}
```

After run this Batch file the contents of screenOut.txt file is this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>if defined Restart goto Begin 

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>rem Place your Batch code here; for example: 

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>rem The date: 05/06/2013, the time: 14:46:54.65 

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>dir TeeMyself.* 
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CCA1-5338

 Directory of C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test

05/06/2013  02:43 p.m.               748 TeeMyself.bat
               1 File(s)            748 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  15,004,553,216 bytes free

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>rem An error message sent to STDERR 

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>verify bad 
An incorrect parameter was
entered for the command.

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>goto :EOF
```

And the contents of the screen is this:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>if defined Restart goto Begin

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>rem TeeMyself.bat: Send output of this Batch file into screenOut.txt file

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>rem Antonio Perez Ayala

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>set Restart=True

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>call "C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test\TeeMyself.bat"   2>&1  | Cscript //nologo //E:JScript "C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents
\test\TeeMyself.bat"  2>screenOut.txt

===================================================
 The same contents of screenOut.txt file goes here
===================================================

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>set Restart=

C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio\My Documents\test
>goto :EOF
```

You should use `"%~DP0screenOut.txt"` name in order to create the text file in the same folder of the Batch file.